# ¿Cómo crear slug en una relación polimorfa?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo dos tablas **works** - **projects** y una tabla común que es **events** con una relación polimorfa. Tanto **works** como **projects** tienen un **slug** que creo con el paquete **eloquent** sin problemas.

He visto en la documentación como hacerlo con dos tablas relacionadas que en mi caso seria algo así:

```
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => ['date', 'time', 'work.title']
        ]
    ];
}
```

He visto también como personalizar el slug, que entiendo que en mi caso usaría **switch** para distinguir **works** de **project** con los campos **eventable_type** - **eventable_id** pero verdaderamente no se como hacerlo, el método para personalizar es este:

```
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'fullname'
        ]
    ];
}

public function getFullnameAttribute() {
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues ya encontré la respuesta, modifique el atributo como os comenté y funciona correctamente.

```
// Creo el slug
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'eventslug'
        ]
    ];
}

// Creo mi propio slug (puedo cambiar el nombre dejando get y atribute)
public function getEventSlugAttribute()
{
    switch ($this->eventable_type) {
        case 'App\Work':
            //Busco la obra
            $work = Work::find($this->eventable_id);
            // Uno las cadenas
            $eventSlug = $this->date . '-' . $this->time . '-' . $work->slug;
            //devuelvo los datos
            return $eventSlug;
            break;

        case 'App\Project':
            //Busco el proyecto
            $project = Project::find($this->eventable_id);
            // Uno las cadenas
            $eventSlug = $this->date . '-' . $this->time . '-' . $project->slug;
            //devuelvo los datos
            return $eventSlug;
            break;
    }
}
```